# Putting 2 vertical scroll bars on the corners of an html page and using css to make them look as gears

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have been trying my best to search for it on forums and such but i don't know why i can't find anything about being able to show 2 scrollbars instead of 1 , one on the left and one on the right ..

I'm not sure if i'm searching at the correct thing as in scrollbars, What I want to do is put gears on the 2  opposite edges of the page and make them "move" when i scroll up/ down, i would prefer if i could make the ones on the left move in a clockwise manner when going down and those on the right in an anti-clockwise manner when I'm scrolling down as well and vice versa

Any help is appreciated even just leading me to where i can find this kind of information, thank you.

What I managed to find was this:

https://jsfiddle.net/TBnqw/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper1">
    <div class="div1">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper2">
    <div class="div2">
    aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper1, .wrapper2{width: 300px; border: none 0px RED;
overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y:hidden;}
.wrapper1{height: 20px; }
.wrapper2{height: 200px; }
.div1 {width:1000px; height: 20px; }
.div2 {width:1000px; height: 200px; background-color: #88FF88;
overflow: auto;}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $(".wrapper1").scroll(function(){
        $(".wrapper2")
            .scrollLeft($(".wrapper1").scrollLeft());
    });
    $(".wrapper2").scroll(function(){
        $(".wrapper1")
            .scrollLeft($(".wrapper2").scrollLeft());
    });
});
```

which makes them both as horizontal, i have tried changing the code itself by changing the overflow-y to scrollbar instead but only the usual scroll bar on the right appeared..i tried also adding flow:left and flow: right to make them appear at the corners of the page but it didn't work as well.

Answer (score -1):

The code you have shared above is on right track but it is synchronizing both elements horizontally. We need horizontal and vertical scrolling and also adjust position of scrollbars.
Here are few changes

```js
$(function() {
  $(".wrapper1").scroll(function() {
    $(".wrapper2").scrollTop($(".wrapper1").scrollTop());
  });
  $(".wrapper2").scroll(function() {
    $(".wrapper1").scrollTop($(".wrapper2").scrollTop());
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper1,
.wrapper2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  /* Adjust height as needed */
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper1 {
  float: left;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.wrapper2 {
  float: right;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.div1,
.div2 {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  /* Set to a large size to enable scrolling */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper1">
  <div class="div1">
  ggggggg hhhhhhhhhh
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper2">
  <div class="div2">
    aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
  </div>
</div>
```